# AJAX request not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, mailchimp

Hey guys and gals,

I have a form that I would like to use AJAX to submit. For the callback function basically what I want to happen is, the form elements disappear (.hide) and are replaced by a div element (which will ready success or something of that nature). I then want the function to pause for 5 seconds and then redirect to a different URL.

The AJAX request successfully submits (as I receive an e-mail to the specified address as I should) but the callback function is not carrying out properly. Any suggestions?

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
        var $form = $('form');
        function register($form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                cache       : false,
                dataType    : 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").hide("slow");
                    $("#form").html('<div class="some-class">Some text that shows up upon successful AJAX request</div>')
                    setTimeout(5000);
                    $(".button").addEventListener("click", function(){
                        window.location.href='http://www.neuyear.net/collections/time-domination-products';
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

**

UPDATE #1

**

This is the only error code that I am getting when I initially load the website (I've heard these errors only pop up in the dev tools and do not affect the user?)
[image]

But then when I submit the form I get this error code
[image]

I've also updated my JavaScript to the below code, taking advice from a few people who posted, it's still not working 100% though

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            cache       : false,
            dataType    : 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").hide("slow");
                $("#form").html('<div class="some-class">Some text that shows up upon successful AJAX request</div>')
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href='http://www.neuyear.net/collections/time-domination-products';
        }, 5000)
    });
});
```

Joey

Comment: any errorin your browser console

Comment: you should check the http response code through fiddler or if you are using chrome then dev tools. Success defines based on response code. Thus it is important that the call to url is returning right value.

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`: You aren't sending JSON data.

Comment: Where did you call register() ?

Comment: how is `register` called?

Comment: @ArunPJohny May be it is not called,i think

Comment: @Joey : Can you add your html form as well

Answer (score 2):

**setTimeout** usage is wrong.

See :

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        var $form = $('form');
        function register($form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                cache       : false,
                dataType    : 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").hide("slow");
                    $("#form").html('<div class="some-class">Some text that shows up upon successful AJAX request</div>')
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href='http://www.neuyear.net/collections/time-domination-products';
                    }, 5000);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Further, the following should ideally be declared separately, if you want the user to click a link and go after ajax success.

```
$(".button").addEventListener("click", function(){
     window.location.href='http://www.neuyear.net/collections/time-domination-products';
})
```

Comment: FYI, it should wait for 5 seconds, not 3.

Comment: @Andy : Edit mess up.